# AngularJS word capitalization filter

Tags: angularjs

I have a short to-do-list program here. It works great, except for the capitalization filter to capitalize the first word of each string. It's flagging me for an injector error but I really don't know what's out of place.

```
<!--TOOD LIST HTML -->
<div ng-controller="todoController" id="todoCTRL">
<form name="frm" ng-submit="addTodo()">
    <input type="hidden" name="newtodo" ng-model="newTodo" required />
</form>

<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" id="listoftodos">
        <span>{{todo.title | capitalize}}</span>
    </li>
</ol>
</div>
<!-- TOOD LIST END HTML -->

<!-- TODOLIST JS -->
<script>
// TODOLIST JS
var app = angular.module('ToDo',[]);
app.controller('todoController',['$scope',function($scope){
$scope.todos = [

];

$scope.addTodo = function(){
    $scope.todos.push({'title':$scope.newTodo})
    $scope.newTodo = ''
}

app.filter('capitalize', function() {
 return function(input) {
  return (!!input) ? input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.substr(1).toLowerCase() : '';
}
});

// TODOLIST END JS
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the actual error.

angular.js:13294 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$injector/unpr?p0=capitalizeFilterProvider%20%3C-%20capitalizeFilter
    at Error (native)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.min.js:43:7
    at Object.d [as get] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.min.js:40:270)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.min.js:43:69
    at Object.d [as get] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.min.js:40:270)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.min.js:157:155
    at V (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.min.js:118:262)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.min.js:116:359
    at p (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.min.js:7:355)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13294(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10007m.$digest @ angular.js:16757m.$apply @ angular.js:17003commands.new item *val @ (index):76d.onresult @ annyang.min.js:6
35www-widgetapi.js:98 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://localhost') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost').g.K @ www-widgetapi.js:98g.O @ www-widgetapi.js:95

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d6gvcfq6/)

Answer (score 1):

when you do `ToDo.filter` you want `ToDo` to refer to your angular module, from the code it looks like it will be assigned to the controller. You want it to look like:

```
var ToDo = angular.module('ToDo',[]);
ToDo.controller(...);
ToDo.filter(...);
```

Comment: You were right, this was not the problem however. It's weird because I can implement the default filters like currency for example with the current setup.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your javascript is well formed - your controller is not properly closed. Also, I would recommend being consistent between either chaining your modules or creating an app variable and defining your modules off that. Try this:

```
var ToDo = angular.module('ToDo', []);

ToDo.controller('todoController', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.todos = [];

    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        $scope.todos.push({'title':$scope.newTodo});
        $scope.newTodo = '';
    }
}]);

ToDo.filter('capitalize', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return (!!input) ? input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.substr(1).toLowerCase() : '';
    }
});
```

Comment: You still have a syntax error with your javascript. Create a JSFiddle because at this point I don't think we're seeing the actual code causing the error.

Comment: I just didn't update it yet. I will update code on here and link a jsfiddle now

Comment: You still had the same syntax error in your controller definition. [Here is an updated and working version of your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6gvcfq6/1/).